# ResourceWarning on closed driver object

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, mobile, automated-tests

I'm starting to use a Page Object design pattern for automated testing in Selenium in Python.
I get to an error which (as I learned) stands that I didn't close some resources.

```
C:\Users\48796\PycharmProjects\test_page_mobile\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py:374: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=512, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 55580), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 4723)>
return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I don't really understand why this appears four times in a row for this code:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from src.Pages.MainPage import MainPage


class Test001(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        desired_capabilities = {
           "platformName": "Android",
           "platformVersion": "11",
            "deviceName": "emulator-5554",  # cmd -> adb devices
            "browserName": "Chrome"
        }

        self.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", desired_capabilities)

    def test_print_title(self):
        main_page = MainPage(self.driver)
        print(main_page.get_title())
    
    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

And as you can see the driver is being closed in the "tearDown" method. What do I do wrong? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out what was an issue. It was an import. I used

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

But for Appium server I should use Appium Webdriver

```
from appium import webdriver
```

which is a part of the package "Appium-Python-Client" (instead of "selenium")